# Traversal of a DAG in Python, looking for all paths from root

Tags: algorithm, traversal, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to do the following:

- Traverse a DAG starting from the root and working down, and perform a (Boolean) test on each node encountered
- If the test is positive, keep searching deeper
- At the end I want to list every **path of connected matching nodes**

If the root is False, the search ends. Similarly, if there is match on a node not connected to the root by nodes with matches, I don't care about it - I don't need to ever get there.

It seems like this should be simple algorithmically, but I can't quite get it. For example the pseudo-code below is incorrect because it adds the parent node repeatedly every time it has a child that fails to match. (I realise that I can just take the set of the results, but I feel like this is doing too much work.)

Incidentally, if a recursive solution is an exceptionally bad idea in Python, I'd be happy to accept a non-recursive solution. I similarly have no preference between breadth-first and depth-first search.

```
func test_node(node)
    if node fails test:
        add path from root to node's parent
    elif node has no children:
        add path from root to node
    else:
        for child in children:
            test_node(child)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the concept of topological sort? Since you're dealing with a directed acyclic graph, it sounds like it would be a good solution, as topological sort can only be performed on such graphs (in fact, a graph is a DAG **if and only if** there exists a topological sort for it).
A topological sort is essentially a way to sort the vertices of a graph in such a way that, for all vertices u,v such that there exists an edge u->v, u must come somewhere before v in the sorting. This is why such a sort is equivalent to the graph being a DAG:

- If it's not directed, there's no way of determining whether an edge (u,v) is in fact u->v or rather v->u, so we cannot create a sort that answers the criteria.
- If the graph contains a cycle, the must be some edge u->v for which v comes somewhere before u in the sort, which contradicts the criteria for topological sort.

Here's an algorithm (code might be syntactically imperfect) that should describe a solution for you:

```py
def check_graph(graph):
    visited = [] * graph.size # number of vertices

    for i in range(graph.size):
        if !visited[i]:
            test_succeed = topo_sort(graph, i, visited)
            if !test_succeed:
                # do what you need
              

def topo_sort(graph, node, visited): # assumed that "graph" is an adjacency list implemented as a dict
    visited[node] = True
    for i in graph[node]:
        if !visited[i]:
            if test_node(i):
                topo_sort(graph, i, visited)
            else:
                return False
    return True
```

I don't really know what that test is and what you aim to do with its results, but this should work for you. Credit goes to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/) GFG article for the skeleton of the functions.
In most cases, topological sorting should produce the actual ordering of the vertices which answers the criteria described above, but here we used the general gist of it and tweaked it here and there for our purpose.

Comment: This is incomplete, since I don't want to visit every node - I want to go backwards from the root, and stop at the end of each "chain" of `True`s.

Answer (score -1):

> At the end I want to list every path of connected matching nodes [from the root to any node connected by nodes where the test returns True]

What do you mean when you refer to a "path"?

Normally in graphs, when people talk about a **path** between node A and node B, they mean a complete list of steps between A and B. I recommend not doing this--there can be exponentially many paths, so you probably don't want to go through them all, let alone have a list of them in memory.

Alternatively, you may mean an **edge**--if there are two nodes A and B, and they both pass your test, you want to output the step (edge) directly between them. This is pretty easy, and you should be able to solve it yourself.

What it looks like your code is doing is some third thing. Since it's not doing what you want I won't comment, but I have no idea what `shortest path` is or what it's doing in there. Can you re-write your function so it returns a list of paths, and doesn't reference functions or data structures not mentioned?

You've said you want all paths from the root to any noe. If you instead want:

- One path for each node
- A set of paths, which includes all nodes

Then submit a new question, this time written more clearly and precisely :)

Comment: 1) You've completely misunderstood my question 2) This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: This is too long to be writable as a comment, in S.O.'s system, but 100% agree. This is essentially supposed to be a polite complaint, that your question is badly explained, with a request for clarification--I've listed 4 options for what you could have meant.